# netbeans maven new module does not show up

Tags: netbeans, maven

In netbeans maven project, if I create a new module it does not show up on UI. I have to restart netbeans for the new module to show up. Right click in the projects window and selecting "reload project" does not seam to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall Netbeans. Something must be broken in your installation.